# Can I use my Amiga2000 Keyboard with a modern PC

Tags: keyboard, compatibility, adapter, amiga

As the title asks, is it possible to use an Amiga 2000 keyboard with a modern computer.

The keyboard in question uses an old plug (A2000 if I remember correctly), not PS/2, or USB.  I currently do not have an adapter to convert it to PS/2 or USB, and wanted to ask if the keyboard would work before I purchased said adapter.

Answer (score 2):

## Possibly. But not without some effort.

Look at the discussion on this [mechanical keyboard thread here](https://deskthority.net/keyboards-f2/amiga-keyboards-with-modern-pcs-t6651.html) as well as [this discussion on this Arduino forum here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=139358.0).

It basically boils down to creating an adapter that would convert the output of the [5-pin DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) on the Amiga keyboard a a modern USB connector.

This page describes using the [Cypress EZ-USB (AN2131)](http://ezhid.sourceforge.net) with [Amiga keyboard specific firmware](http://ezhid.sourceforge.net/amikbd.html) (EzHID Amiga Keyboard Firmware) to convert the input. But as described in [this mechanical keyboard thread](https://deskthority.net/keyboards-f2/amiga-keyboards-with-modern-pcs-t6651.html):

> That is a protocol converter-firmware for the AN2131 serial-to-USB chip, used as an adapter for an external A2000/A3000 keyboard. A compiled file is available in the archive that you can download from EzHID's web page. The problems seem to be getting hold of a device with that chip and programming it ... Not exactly a ready-made solution.

And [this thread on this Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=139358.0) explains how to convert an Arduino Leonardo into an Amiga 500/1000/2000 keyboard interface:

> this turns your Arduino Leonardo into an AMIGA 500/1000/2000 Keyboard Interface which means that you can use your Amiga Keyboard as an HID Keyboard on your PC/Mac/PS3/Raspberry Pi or whatever. (like keyrah) All you need is the Amiga Keyboard and the Arduino without any shield or additional hardware. It does not work with Amiga 600/1200 Keyboards since they have no serial interface. It's also possible to hook up 2 digital joysticks (e.g. competition pro) with db9 connector.

That said, it seems—again based on [the discussion on that mechanical keyboard forum](https://deskthority.net/keyboards-f2/amiga-keyboards-with-modern-pcs-t6651.html)—a [Teensy USB development board](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Teensy) might be a more supported option for general keyboard input translation development:

> The Teensy USB Development Board by PJRC is a line of small inexpensive circuit boards with a microcontroller that offers a plethora of I/O pins and a USB interface.
>
> The Teensy version 2.0 has become popular for many enthusiast keyboard projects, either as a keyboard controller or a [protocol converter](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Converter). It sports a AVR ATMEGA32U4 8-bit microcontroller ("µC"), 16 MHz clock (16 MIPS), 25 I/O lines and a USB client port. There is also a larger variant: the Teensy++ 2.0 with a AT90USB1286 chip that has more I/O lines.
>
> The Teensy 3.0, Teensy 3.1 and Teensy LC have microcontrollers based on ARM Cortex M-series. These have so far not reached much popularity because of lack of available firmware. The LC model is a "low cost" variant that is (mostly) pin-compatible with the Teensy 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sound like it might be a [DIN Connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector)?  If that is the case, then yes it will work if you can find a DIN to PS/2 adapter.  I'm using an old IBM "clicky" keyboard right now with that setup (DIN keyboard plugged into a PS/2 port via adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, and not without a *specially* designed adaptor.

Lets start with the fact that no PC has used a DIN connector for a keyboard in *roughly* 30 years - and there is no support for either the *physical connectors* or *electrical protocol*

According to pinouts.ru The [A2000 keyboard](http://old.pinouts.ru/Inputs/KeyboardAmiga5_pinout.shtml) seems to use a [standard PC pinout](http://old.pinouts.ru/Inputs/KeyboardPC5_pinout.shtml) *but* according to this [forum post](http://www.amiga.org/forums/showthread.php?t=59448), the protocols are different. That is to say, *unless* your adaptor is specifically designed to do amiga 2000 flavoured DIN -> modern keyboard ports, it is unlikely to work